# How to set active tab dynamically in ejs templates of nodejs express app?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

This is my header template, which will load to every page.

```
<!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">

      <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html"><%= title %><span>.</span></a></h1>
      <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
      <!-- <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="/assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>-->

      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <% 
          const menu = [
    {
        name: 'Home',
        url: '/'
    },
    {
        name: 'About',
        url: '/about'
    },
    {
      name: 'Services',
      url: '/services'
  },
  {
    name: 'Portfolio',
    url: '/portfolio'
},
{
  name: 'Team',
  url: '/team'
},
{
  name: 'RatesCalculator',
  url: '/ratesCalculator'
},
{
  name: 'Contact',
  url: '/contact'
}
]
          
          
          for ( let i in menu ) { %> 
            <% if ( menu[i].name.toLowerCase() == activestate.toLowerCase() ) { %> 
    
              <li><a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="<%= menu[i].url %>" ><%= menu[i].name %></a></li>
    
            <% } else { %>
    
              <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="<%= menu[i].url %>" ><%= menu[i].name %></a></li>
    
            <% } %>
        <% } %>
       
        </ul>
        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
      </nav><!-- .navbar -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->
```

To set it dynamically, the active tab, I am using the logic below in template and the middleware in index.js.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req)
    res.locals.title = "Marker";//To set website title
    req.active = req.path.split('/')[1] // [0] will be empty since routes start with '/'
    if (req.length === 0) req.active = "Home"
    next();
});
```

It is working but I feel it is bit complicated and repetitive code is there.

Can you please suggest a better approach.